# Android RotateAnimation - rotate arrow back and forth

Tags: android, animation, rotateanimation

In my application, I am rotating a clock hand to the desired amount of minutes. This works good with RotateAnimation. Now what I want to do is to return the hand back to the starting position (0 minutes).

For example:
I first rotate the hand like this:

```
final RotateAnimation anim = new RotateAnimation(0f, ammountDegress, RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 1f);
anim.setFillAfter(true);
anim.setFillEnabled(true)
```

Then I would like to move the hand back to it's starting position, so that means I should be calling a RotateAnimation after the first animation ends.

The problem is that the pivots have changed, how I can I set the pivot position to the exact position as previous? So that the rotating point is again at the same position of the clock hand.

**Edit** To make it more clearer - I would like to have something like a fixed point pivot that doesn't change with the rotation, so I am always rotating the hand around the same point.

I hope you can understand what I mean.

Comment: +1 for using float arguments... Just an edit...   rotationAnimationObjectOfHourHand = new RotateAnimation(getStartAngleOfHourHand(),getEndAngleOfHourHand(), Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT,.027f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0); use float arguements of the order of ".01"